# I have a problem with construct regular expression

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have a data frame where row in one column looks like this:

```
<title>Some text</title>

<selftext>Some text</selftext>
```

This above is one row in one column.
The problem is that not every row looks like this. I have to implement that rows which not looks like this was removed.

I tried to use code below:

```
pattern = "<title>[a-zA-Z0-9]</title>\n\n<selftext>[a-zA-Z0-9]</selftext>"
for row in df.column_name:
    if row == pattern:
        print(row)
```

and I don't have any rows printed, although I should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea for what is wrong with the pattern would be that you set a range but only allow *exactly* one character. Use this to allow any content within title and selftext tags which have *at least* one character.

```
pattern = "<title>[a-zA-Z0-9]+</title>\n\n<selftext>[a-zA-Z0-9]+</selftext>"
```

Also you did not call an actual regex pattern. You just did a string comparison. So unless the content would be exactly `[a-zA-Z0-9]` it wouldnt match.

Use it like this:

```
import re
pattern = "<title>[a-zA-Z0-9]+</title>\n\n<selftext>[a-zA-Z0-9]+</selftext>"
for row in df.column_name:
    if re.match(pattern, row):
        print(row)
```

Edit: Unless you also want to filter the content by following exactly the right character set and numbers range, I would recommend making the pattern much more broad. Basically XML allows for everything except Tags (`<`, `>`) within the tags. So you could just match until the next opening tag. While you're at it you can also allow empty tags as these can also occur in XML.

```
import re
pattern = "<title>[^<]*</title>\n\n<selftext>[^<]*</selftext>"
for row in df.column_name:
    if re.match(pattern, row):
        print(row)
```

Comment: Your pattern doesnt include whitespaces too. So if every content has a whitespace it wont match either. Try `pattern = "<title>[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+</title>\n\n<selftext>[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+</selftext>"`.

Comment: See my edit. Try to allow more within the tags.